# Confusing IEEE-754 Subnormal/Normal: why FLT_MIN is bigger than 1.40e-45?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, subnormal-numbers

I noticed in C/C++ that `FLT_MIN` is about `1.1754943508222875e-38` while `FLT_MAX` is `3.40282346639e+38`, I was expecting more symmetric values around zero until I realized that `FLT_MIN` represents the minimum value close to zero, not the absolute minimum value which is in this case `-FLT_MAX`. So I wrote this:

```py
>>> exp = 0
>>> mantissa = 0
>>> 2**(exp - 126) * (1 + mantissa / 2**23)
1.1754943508222875e-38
```

I was confident, but when I played around with this excellent [FloatConverter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) I found that my interpretation is wrong:

When `exp==0` and `mantissa==0` I don't get `1.1754943508222875e-38`, but `0`:

[image]

Moreover, the above `FLT_MIN` value isn't quite achieved in the same way:

[image]

It seems if the exponent is equal to `0`, we are in a special case named `denormalized` in which we get rid of the `+1`:

```
2**((exp if exp else 1) - 127) * ((1 if exp else 0) + mantissa / 2**23)
```

In this case, I could have: `mantissa = 1`, and therefore my number equals: `1.401298464324817e-45` which is smaller than `FLT_MIN`. Oh damned!

So I don't understand why I can get smaller values than the smallest value.

Comment: @nowox, `FLT_MIN` (about 1.17549435e-38) is the smallest non-zero _normal_ value.  (values with 24-bit precision).  `FLT_TRUE_MIN` (about `1.40129846e-45`) is the smallest non-zero value.  That commonly has 1 bit of precision.